Python code doesn't format data correctly when writing to csv file, spreads it over multiple lines instead of all on one line
def SaveToCsv(subject, question, answer, questiontype):
    with open(r"BankOfQuestions.csv", "a", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as Bank:
        writer = csv.writer(Bank, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow([question, answer, questiontype, subject])

def AddNewQuestion(subject):
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title(f"Add a new question for {subject}")

    if subject == "New Subject":
        Label1 = tk.Label(window, text="Enter name of subject")
        Label1.pack()
        SubjectTitle = tk.StringVar()
        NameOfSubject = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=SubjectTitle, font=("Ariel", 10))
        NameOfSubject.pack()

        Label2= tk.Label(window, text="Enter the question", pady=12)
        Label2.pack()
        Question = tk.Text(window, font=("Ariel", 10), height=9)
        Question.pack()

        Label3 = tk.Label(window, text= "Enter the answer", pady=12)
        Label3.pack()
        Answer= tk.Text(window, font=("Ariel", 10), height=9)
        Answer.pack()

        qtypes = ["multiple choice", "written"]
        QuestionType = tk.StringVar()
        QuestionType.set("Select question type")
        drop = tk.OptionMenu(window, QuestionType, *qtypes)
        drop.pack(pady=12)

        Submit = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command= lambda: SaveToCsv(SubjectTitle.get(), Question.get("1.0", "end"), Answer.get("1.0", "end"), QuestionType.get()))
        Submit.pack()
    else:
        Label2= tk.Label(window, text="Enter the question", pady=12)
        Label2.pack()
        Question = tk.Text(window, font=("Ariel", 10), height=9)
        Question.pack()

        Label3 = tk.Label(window, text= "Enter the answer", pady=12)
        Label3.pack()
        Answer= tk.Text(window,font=("Ariel", 10), height=9)
        Answer.pack()

        qtypes = ["multiple choice", "written"]
        QuestionType = tk.StringVar()
        QuestionType.set("Select question type")
        drop = tk.OptionMenu(window, QuestionType, *qtypes)
        drop.pack(pady=12)

        Submit = tk.Button(window, text="Sumbit", command= lambda :SaveToCsv(subject, Question.get("1.0","end"), Answer.get("1.0","end"), QuestionType.get()))
        Submit.pack()

#Function for user adding their own questions
def openAdding():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title("Add a question")
    #Initializes list for subjects to be stored in
    UniqueSubject = []
    #opens csv file
    with open("BankOfQuestions.csv", "r") as Bank:
        Stuff = csv.reader(Bank)
        #Looks at the subject column
        for line in Stuff:
            subject = line[3]
            #Checks if the item being looked at if the header, blank or currently in the unique subject list
            if subject == "Subject" or subject == "" or subject in UniqueSubject:
                #if any of the conditions are true, it does nothing
                pass
            else:
                #Add the item in the subject column to the UniqueSubject list
                UniqueSubject.append(subject)
            UniqueSubject.append("New Subject")
        #Sets menu to a string and its starting value to "Pick a subject" to make it clear what its for
        menu = tk.StringVar()
        menu.set("Pick a Subject")
        #Creates a dropdown box with the opening string of menu,
        #the options are all the subjects in the UniqueSubject list
        drop = tk.OptionMenu(window, menu, *UniqueSubject, command= lambda x:    AddNewQuestion(menu.get()),)
        drop.pack()
    
        Quitter = tk.Button(window, text="Quit", font=("Ariel", 20), command=window.destroy)
        Quitter.pack()


I am making a quiz program in python and want to allow the user to add their own questions and store them in a csv file.
I want the code to write the values for question, answer, questiontype and subject to 1 line in the csv file.
hypothetically, if these are the values:
question: when did WWII start
answer: 1939
questiontype: multiple choice
subject: History

I want the code to write this to the csv file as follows:
when did WWII start,1939,multiple choice,History

However, what the code writes to the csv file is:

Any idea where the quotations marks come from and how to amend the code so it writes the data in the way I want it to?
sorry if the code is not very clear i am new to coding and have to do this for school.

I'm not sure why, but all your entry values end with a newline.

Use SubjectTitle.get().rstrip(), and similar for the other entries, to remove the trailing whitespace.

Per Barmar's suggestion:
def SaveToCsv(subject, question, answer, questiontype):
    # Remove trailing new lines
    subject = subject.rstrip()
    question = question.rstrip()
    answer = answer.rstrip()
    questiontype = questiontype.rstrip()

    with open(r"BankOfQuestions.csv", "a", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as Bank:
        writer = csv.writer(Bank, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow([question, answer, questiontype, subject])

The problem is your values somehow ends with new lines, so we need to remove them before writing to the file. I assume that all of your values are strings.

That solved the issue. Thanks
